# Ansible and Cisco

Tags: cisco, ansible

I'm new to ansible and I've been asked to provide a mechanism for our support guys (who don't have rights to the Cisco switches) a means to shut/no shut ports.

I've googled and I can see how to do that but I need to ensure that they can't shut a trunk port as that could isolate the switch.

Is this possible?  Could I get a pointer on where to look to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my mind I see complicated scheme, where you can use `Ansible` together with `Jenkins` to do it. You could do Jenkins job for each switch where provide list of ports, which could be turned off/on.